# How to DELETE a specific row from database with Flask-SQLAlchemy given TWO conditions?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Here is my model:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Amazon(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'amazon1'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String)
    url = db.Column(db.String)
    priceAlert = db.Column(db.Float)
    useragent = db.Column(db.String)

    def __init__(self, email, url, priceAlert, useragent):
        self.email = email
        self.url = url
        self.priceAlert = priceAlert
        self.useragent = useragent
```

[Entries in SQL data base. I want to delete only 1 row, depending on the URL I use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxVzm.png)

I want to imitate: DELETE FROM Amazon WHERE email = ? AND url = ?

I am getting the error: sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Could not evaluate current criteria in Python with the following code.
The for statement cycles through the database:

```
        d = db.session.query(Amazon).all()
        for entry in d:
            email_1 = entry.email
            url_1 = entry.url

            if email_1 == email and url_1 == url:
                db.session.query(Amazon).filter(entry.email == email_1). \
                    filter(entry.url == url_1).delete()
                db.session.commit()
```

I also tried:

```
            if email_1 == email and url_1 == url:
                db.session.query(Amazon).filter(and_(entry.email(email_1),
                entry.url(url_1)))
                db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why loop through all records in the table when you can simply use the `filter_by` functionality and append the `.delete()` to turn the statement into a DELETE query like so?

```
Amazon.query.filter_by(email=email_1, url=url_1).delete()
db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The left hand side of the filter expressions should be the model class attribute being tested:

```py
db.session.query(Amazon).filter(Amazon.email == email_1). \
    filter(Amazon.url == url_1).delete()
```